# How to adjust external project to my project on android studio?

Tags: android-studio

https://github.com/Semantive/waveform-android

I want to add this project to mine, but I don't know how to do that.

(I am just started the android programming...)

Can you tell me step-by-step how to add it?

Should I download or pull to my project?

Comment: Start by understanding android gradle build system. https://gradle.org/getting-started-android-build/

Comment: @agent_hunt Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by downloading the project to your computer. You can then go to File > New > Import Project and select the project you want to add.